# JUnit test for console input and output

Tags: java, junit, io, console, user-input

I have only one method main. How to check System.out.println() and replace Scanner to input values automatically using JUnit?

P.S. Please, provide some solutions...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int res = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int num = arr[i];
        /*.....*/
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna learn how to work with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, extract the awkward dependencies so that you can test without them. Change `main` to simply:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  doWork(new Scanner(System.in), System.out);
}

// TODO: Rename to something meaningful
public static void doWork(Scanner input, PrintStream output) {
  // Remainder of code
}
```

(Consider using a `Writer` instead of a `PrintStream` for `output`.)

Then you don't really need to unit test `main` - but you can test `doWork` using a `Scanner` based on a `StringReader`, and output based on a `StringWriter`, providing whatever input you want and checking the output.

Comment: How can I use this to have for example, multiple inputs corresponding to multiple prompts for information?

Comment: I have the same question. Let me know if you found something...!

Comment: @Aman: Sorry, I must have not seen this comment before. You'd provide a `Scanner` that returns all the values you'd expect the user to enter, basically.

Comment: Thanks. But I used the System Rules library https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and this is what I ended up doing.

First off, I'd suggest doing as @Jon-Skeet suggests and instead of using the `main(String[])` method of the class, create a separate method.

Then you can have that method take in an `InputStream` as a parameter and then create a `Scanner` object within the method that uses the passed `InputStream` as its source. That way you can pass any `InputStream`, such as `System.in`, to the method when it's called (elaboration below).

```java
package my.package;

import ...;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void myMethod(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(inputStream);

        // Do stuff with the Scanner such as...
        String input = inputScanner.nextLine();
    
        System.out.println("You inputted " + input);
    }
}
```

Now, in your production source code you can call `myMethod` and pass it `System.in` as an argument as such, `myMethod(System.in);`

And then in your unit tests, you can create mock input values via a `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```java
package my.package;

import ...;

public class MyClassTest
{
    @Test
    void testMyMethod()
    {
        // Simulates a user inputting the string "Mock input" and hitting enter
        assertDoesNotThrow(myMethod(new ByteArrayInputStream("Mock input\n".getBytes())));
    }
}
```

And voila, you now have a way to pass your method mock input as well as it being more modular overall.

I just want to point out without getting too much into it, that when working with `System.in`, one needs to be careful about closing it and in unit tests when working with input streams, one needs to be careful about reusing a reference to the same `InputStream` as its state can persist across uses.