# How to test output/input in java

Tags: java, testing, junit, io

I am aware that this might be a duplicate (forgive me if that is the case), any one of these two could be a duplicate to what I'm searching for, but as I have no idea if they do answer my problem I'll ask it here anyway.

[JUnit test for console input and output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331696/junit-test-for-console-input-and-output),
[JUnit test for System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

My assignment (school):

We're to write a simple compiler that tracks the colour of a pencil and movement across the x- and y-axis. i.e.

Input:

> % This is a comment
>   % Now we're making a square
>   DOWN.
>   FORW 1. LEFT 90.
>   FORW 1. LEFT 90.
>   FORW 1. LEFT 90.
>   FORW 1. LEFT 90.

Output:

> #0000FF 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
>   #0000FF 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
>   #0000FF 1.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000
>   #0000FF 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000

My problem:

To get a passing grade our code is subjected to a rigorous series of tests, many of these give you no clue as to what went wrong. i.e.

> "A random generated program on 1215 bytes, with 1 syntax error"

So I feel that a great part of this assignment is to learn how to write good test-code, I've been thinking about trying to use JUnit (or perhaps I should use something else?). My input comes from System.in and the output goes through System.out.println().

Hopefully there is a way to do this by using existing textfiles (went through some difficulties earlier with assertEquals and super long strings full of \n). To clarify: I want to test I/O (through text-files) of my Java-program and I can't find any good clear explanation on how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part writing unit tests is separating the code you want to test from boilerplate/well-tested code out of given frameworks - so you might create classes which create the output but separate the part of reading the input from `System.in` and writing it to `System.out` from your business logic to concentrate on the "serious" parts.

Answer (score 0):

I came against this problem when refactoring some legacy code recently. I extracted input/output into new classes and made them dependency of my program. Using dependency injection I inserted mocks/fakes so I could define what will be the input and what the output should be.

```
public class InputReader {

    private static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String nextLine() {
        return SCANNER.nextLine();
    }

}

public class OutputPrinter {

    public void println(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

And then the test using [mockito](http://mockito.org/):

```
public class MainProgramTest {

    private final InputReader inputReader = mock(InputReader.class);
    private final OutputPrinter outputPrinter = mock(OutputPrinter.class);

    @Test
    public void playsSimpleGame() {
        when(inputReader.nextLine())
                .thenReturn("hello")
                .thenReturn("help")
                .thenReturn("exit");

        MainProgram mainProgram = new MainProgram(inputReader, outputPrinter);
        mainProgram.run();

        InOrder inOrder = inOrder(inputReader, outputPrinter);
        inOrder.verify(inputReader).nextLine(); // -> "hello"
        inOrder.verify(outputPrinter).println("\"hello\" is not recognised command, type \"help\" for known commands");
        inOrder.verify(inputReader).nextLine(); // -> "help"
        inOrder.verify(outputPrinter).println("This is help, the only known commands are \"help\" and \"exit\"");
        inOrder.verify(inputReader).nextLine(); // -> "exit"
        inOrder.verify(outputPrinter).println("Goodbye");
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(inputReader, outputPrinter);
    }

}
```