# Java / Selenium WebDriver eternal load with scanner

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to make authorization in instagram with selenium + scanner. However,  the compiler cannot compile this code in any way, I have an eternal load. What am I doing wrong?
There is my code of my programm.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent;


public class MainPageTest {
    @Test
    public void openPage() {
        Scanner user_login = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your username: ");
        String user_login1= user_login.nextLine();
        user_login.close();

        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Kirill\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addPreference("general.useragent.override",userAgent);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginForm\"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input")).sendKeys(user_login1);
```

External load screenshot :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgsID.png)

Comment: Also ,  I am trying to type something in the console but nothing is displayed. The keyboard is OK.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635698/junit-testing-for-user-input-using-scanner check this