# How to mock console application with Scanner Java

Tags: java, mocking

I build an console application with lots of void methods and a Scanner. In the simple example: How can I mock a scanner to print to the console? Given console output `"Do a"` how can I respond via mock with `"a"`?

My test is failing - `"Mockito cannot mock/spy because : final class`".

**Class to test**

```java
public class Class {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public void startScreen() {
        System.out.println("Do a");

        while (!scanner.hasNext("a")) {
            System.out.println("No valid option!");
            scanner.next();
        }
        String input;
        input = scanner.next();

        if(input.equals("a")){
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }
}
```

**Mock test**

```java
@Test
void test() {
    Scanner scanner = Mockito.mock(Scanner.class);
    Mockito.when(scanner.nextLine()).thenReturn("a");
    Class s = new Class();
    s.startScreen();
}
```

Comment: This seems relevant to what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635698/junit-testing-for-user-input-using-scanner

Comment: Indeed, I saw that. The relevant part where he tries to mock the scanner is commented with "Scanner cannot be mocked because the class is final." - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31635953/19255249. Not sure if there is a work around with mock. @JLCarveth

Comment: Forget about mocking scanner, and simply replace the input stream as the top answer suggests.

Comment: Now I think how I can use this with Mockito, because I need to use Mockito. @JLCarveth